# VisualForce Error: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes. To save

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have read other answer regarding the same problem but still, it doesn't change anything at all, I still get the error...

I'm trying to save the details in the form to salesforce but it says

> "Formula Expression is required on the action attributes. "

when I tried saving it.

```
<apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="!save"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="!cancel"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock >
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not used formula expression in

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="!save"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="!cancel"/>
```

for both commandbuttons.
Use as

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Formula expression implies other notation of the action attribute:

```
action="!save"
```

should be

```
action="{!save}"
```

Same for cancel action.

Comment: I've tried it and thank you, there is no more error, however, the the details are not saved...

Comment: pls post a new question for that, including apex class and vf page