# Visualforce page override for Individual: "VisualForce Error: Formula Expression is required on the action attributes"

Tags: visualforce, skuid

I have created an object record page for the `Individual` object using Skuid.

I am trying to override the "View" button.

I have created a Visualforce page which acts as the override.

```
<apex:page standardController="Individual"
  extensions="skuid.Redirects"
  action="{!redirect}&objectType=Individual&actionType=View">
</apex:page>
```

When I login as a user, to try and access this record page, from the link on a contact, I am presented with the error below

> Formula Expression is required on the action attributes

I searched stackexchange and reffered to the [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75341/visualforce-error-formula-expression-is-required-on-the-action-attributes-to-s) for help on the error. I can't see what I have done wrong. Has anyone else experienced such a problem with the new `Individual` object? If so then how did they fix the issue?

Comment: Have you checked this [**link**](https://community.skuid.com/skuid/topics/formula-expression-is-required-on-the-action-attributes) on Skuid community, if that's your case?

Comment: I have, it doesn't help because this problem is in the sandbox, so all users have access to the managed package license. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102179/installed-packages-in-sandbox-not-working-after-refresh-from-prod

Comment: Try concatenating entirely within the merge field. `{!redirect + '&parameters=values'}`